# Why do the COVID vaccines contain the cationic lipids they do?

Tags: lipids, covid, liposomes

Why did Moderna & Pfizer specifically pick their SM-102 and ALC-0315 cationic lipids with tertiary amines, branched tails, long linker chains, and small hydroxyl head groups? Are the large tails and packing parameter to keep the lipid from leaking out of the liposomal membrane? Why not use any other large hydrophobic groups? Thanks!

Comment: Are those vaccine's lipids very similar to our cell wall? I was told a while ago that due to the similarity, those lipid balls could just "merge" with cell walls and bring the content in the lipid balls inside the cell. I was pretty satisfied with that answer as I wasn't even aware of the amount of nuances that existed in the lipid itself.